# Can the php.ini default file be downloaded by itself for different versions?

Tags: php

Instead of copying php.ini files over from old PHP versions whenever I upgrade PHP, I would like to be able to download the newest php-recommended.ini file from somewhere by itself. I have searched for this option on php.net but I could not find it.

It seems like it should be an easy question, but I have not been able to answer it.

Thanks for any help!
Metropolis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab it from GitHub:

https://github.com/php/php-src

It will be in the root of the trunk/tag/branch you're dealing with.

Comment: I actually like this one better only because its graphical lol

Comment: I think the best answer for me would be http://svn.php.net/viewvc/. Just so I could see where all of the source files are.