# The mcrypt extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-13.10, linux-mint

I just followed the tutorial located at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu while fixing multiple other errors that I came across along the way and I'm stuck with one last error. When I log in to phpMyAdmin, there's a huge red error at the bottom saying "The mcrypt extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.".
I installed everything listed in the tutorial on Ubuntu 13.10 via putty.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Funny I just got this today reinstalling the lamp stack.  Thanks!

Comment: After fresh ubuntu 14.04 and LAMP install, all I needed to do was add the mod: sudo php5enmod mcrypt. cheers.

Comment: I got "ln: failed to create symbolic link /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini: File exists" when executing second line. It seems its already done for you in the first step.

Comment: @BasilMusa thanks; which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Second line is too important, solve my issue thanks. +1

Comment: I followed every instruction here and in other places but in vain. ubuntu 14.04.3 -- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 -- nginx/1.8.1 -- Server version: 5.7.10 - MySQL -- Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.47 -- phpMyAdmin Version: 4.0.10deb1....anyone have an idea?

Comment: Still happening, and the server itself is not a dependency ? (Probably due to the MariaDB etc. ambiguity.  Purging marks Apache2 as no longer required ?

Comment: @mckenzm Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Apologies, my versions always come from Ubuntu repositories, currently Trusty, more specifically this version came from the aws sources for eu-west-1. (these are not strictly mirrors and they are not identical from region to region). So 4:4.0.10-1 but this is likely a package issue then.

Comment: Last two lines worked for me. Ubuntu server 14.04.4.

Answer (score 25):

I've followed the exact tutorial with OP on digital ocean. The only steps that missing is to

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and the error gone after restarting the apache service

Comment: What those two command do is this: the 1st line is enabling module named 'mcrypt', and then restart apache2 to update the config. You can see the enabled module from `/etc/apache2/mods-available`. Enjoy LAMP life :)

Answer (score 6):

Adding this answer for anyone who encounters this issue with **Linux Mint 17**.

Just installed a LAMP stack on and was getting this error.   The mycrpt.ini file was already inst the /etc/php5/mods-available directory.  All that needed to be done was to run the command to enable the module:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Restart apache after that and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I just stuffed a symbolic link into the Apache portion of php configuration. Platform:
Xubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Details:

1. cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
2. sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini 20-mcrypt.ini
3. ls -l to see if the new link is there
4. sudo apache2ctl restart

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

For those using a LEMP stack (nginx & php5-fpm), this is the solution

```
apt-get install php5-mcrypt
php5enmod mcrypt
service php5-fpm restart
service nginx restart
```

(run each with sudo, naturally)

Comment: am still stuck with this on phpmyadmin...any ideas??

Comment: @Jadeye Stuck with what, more precisely?

Comment: Thanks! Important critical steps for nginx stacks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt; php5enmod mcrypt; service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Mac OS X Yosemite using **Terminal**, and I fix this error

> **the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system**

by running the following commands :

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install php54-mcrypt
```