# Can't login to phpmyadmin, no error message sgown

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATED POST

I installed Phpmyadmin in my Ubuntu station, then I tried to connect but I can't , it doesn't show any error message, when I try differnent wrong user/pass, it shows  error message, I followed both this

[phpMyAdmin won't let me login - no error shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903764/phpmyadmin-wont-let-me-login-no-error-shown)

and this

[Cannot login to phpMyAdmin, no errors shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023619/cannot-login-to-phpmyadmin-no-errors-shown)

But didn't help, 
I can connect to mysql no problem, and I use mySql for my localhost, so no other user.
I edited php.ini :

```
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/sessions"
```

and I changed the permissions / owner of that file :

```
#ls -l
>>drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data /sessions
```

Every try of connection creates already a session that I can find in /var/lib/php/sessions, so I don't think it is problem of connection, in apache error.log I see nothing.

Comment: What username are you using?

Comment: I think it is more helpful to explain why downvoted my question. I said already it is not a duplicated post, if you think it is then please let me know.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I  am using 'root'

Comment: So does `root` have a password set on it yet? If not then leave the password field blank

Comment: @RiggsFolly the root has a password. I tried empty and I got error

Comment: If root has a password then "trying empty" will not work.

Comment: my user/password are correct, I can use them in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/99571/stuck-on-login-phpmyadmin) post I knew that I need mcrypt library.
so I did it with

`sudo apt-get php5.6-mcrypt` (depending on your php version),

this also installed few other packages with, may, were the reason

`(libapache2-mod-php5.6 php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-curl php5.6-json php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mysql php5.6-opcache php5.6-readline php5.6-xml)`

So to run phpmyAdmin properly better to check those liraries.