# Unable to login to phpmyadmin and no errors shown

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

Exactly similar to this question
[Cannot login to phpMyAdmin, no errors shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023619/phpmyadmin-wont-log-in-no-errors-shown)

tried almost every workaround possible including purging and reinstalling phpmyadmin,reconfiguring database etc

Token id appears in the address bar and then redirected to the opening page. Any help?

Comment: dont use phpMyAdmin.. its full of bugs! you should switch over to something like mysql workbench

Comment: Maybe a problem with the session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this steps yet ?

```
(1) Install php-mcrypt
(2) Clear all cookies
(3) Set correct timezone and enable NTP
(4) Edit /etc/php/php.ini and enable mcrypt.so, and default timezone
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL in address bar. Try to change the schema from http://localhost to https://localhost - works for me in same case. Phpmyadmin want secured connection. I we set local self signed certificate.
P.S. i see that the post is very old but the problem persist in newer Ubuntu (18.04) installation too